# How to improve WebView on Android Eclaire?

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, android-webview, android-2.1-eclair, nook

I have an old device (Nook Simple Touch). It based on Android 2.1. I am writing simple application for this device (only for personal usage). This application is a WebView linked to special WEB-site. Site was build using JQuery Mobile.

I get a trouble with it. WebView on this device is not perfect and shows some elements incorrectly. New versions of WebView works well.

Is it possible to improve WebView on old version of Android? May be here is a way to upgrade it or i can use some library for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's nothing WebView related you can do here.

jQuery Mobile performs badly on Android systems below 2.3

To be more specific, jQuery Mobile performs badly on Android systems below 4.0, however, performance drops even further if Android 2.2 and below is used.

On Android 4.0 you could have used Crosswalk to make your application faster, however, it is limited to Android 4+.

The good news is you are not out of possibilities.

CSS3 is the main reason jQuery Mobile performs purely on Android 2.X devices. You can disable jQuery Mobile styling and do it on your own making sure not to use or overuse CSS3, especially CSS3 drop shadows.

Another possibility would be to upgrade the Android version. Unfortunately, an official upgrade was never released nor there was a custom ROM on XDA developers.